# Tar up only 3 specific files in command line with linux

Tags: linux, tar, gzip

Is it possible with one command to tar up 3 files into one tar archive?

**For example, tar up:**

> public_html.tar.gz
>
> dbapp.sql
>
> dbwp.sql

into a tar file called **bak.tar.gz**

Answer (score 12):

```
tar acf bak.tar.gz public_html.tar.gz dbapp.sql dbwp.sql
```

Or if you dont have `a` option

```
tar zcf bak.tar.gz public_html.tar.gz dbapp.sql dbwp.sql
```